# Customize user profile page

Tags: users

I want to fully customize the user profile page. I want to be able to show only the fields that I want, display views, blocks, etc...

Some users will be able to see others users pages so I really need to customize this my way.

Is this possible? Where should I code?

I found a user-profile.tpl.php and it only has this code:

[image]

Should I get rid of this code and write a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete it, copy it into your theme with the other templates and adjust it there, your theme will override the one in core once you clear cache.